# Which is right idiom “ I don’t care a pin for it OR I care a pin for it “

Tags: idioms

Which is right “ I don’t care a pin for it OR I care a pin for it

Comment: You ***dont*** care a pin for.... https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+care+two+pins

Comment: "I _don't_ care..." Also see: [I don't give a ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465031/archaic-phrase-similar-to-not-give-a-damn)

Comment: See also [giving a damn ... do you care or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404888/giving-a-damn-do-you-care-or-not) but also [Which is correct – 'could care less' or 'couldn't care less?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/706/which-is-correct-could-care-less-or-couldnt-care-less)